# My slider will only appear when I hit the arrows.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Don't now where it's going wrong. Anybody got an idea? I'm new at bootstrap and tried a couple of things, also things i found on google but it didn't do the trick.

thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container">  
<div class="row-fluid">  
<div class="span12">

<div id="slider" class="carousel slide">

    <div class="carousel-inner">   

        <div class="item">
            <img src="beelden/1.jpg">
            <div class="carousel">
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="item">
            <img src="beelden/2.jpg">
            <div class="carousel">
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="item">
            <img src="beelden/3.jpg">
            <div class="carousel">
            </div>
       </div>


    </div>  
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slider" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slider" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>   
</div>        
</div>   
</div>     


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which version of `bootstrap` are you using?

Comment: Oh crap, I filled in 3 but it's bootstrap 2.3.2, sorry

Comment: Follow-up, are you using `css` as well?

Comment: Are you saying that, the pictures are not appearing as you load the page?

Comment: Yes, only when the arrows at the bottom of the page are pushed the images appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found where the problem is. Please have a look at [jsffiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zWU3/).

There wasn't an item selected to be `active`, just put active into the first picture you want to show. :)

From

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="beelden/1.jpg">
  <div class="carousel">
  </div>
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="active item">
  <img src="beelden/1.jpg">
  <div class="carousel">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @feng if it helped you, please kindly select my answer. To keep me motivated, thank you!